# Stop consuming RabbitMQ messages in case of a serious global error

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I have developed a simple client for receiving messages from a rabbitMQ queue.

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "#{'${rabbitmq.queues}'.split(',')}")
public void receiveMessage(Message message, @Header(AmqpHeaders.CONSUMER_QUEUE) String queue) {
logger.debug("message payload as string {}", new String(message.getBody()));
```

I am having a standard SSL handshake error at the moment because I haven't installed my private key. 
Since there is an error, the message is not consumed, it stays in the queue.
The problem is that my client continues to try to consume the same message indefinitely. Could you advice me with a solution to this?
What I want is, in case of a serious global error, to stop consuming messages for a "while". Maybe a Thread sleep? Is there a spring solution to this? Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

By default, the listener container will attempt to reconnect every 5 seconds.

You can reconfigure the container(s), by adding a `BackOff` to the listener container factory; something like...

```
@Bean
public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory() {
    SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
    factory.setConcurrentConsumers(3);
    final ExponentialBackOff backOff = new ExponentialBackOff();
    backOff.setInitialInterval(5_000);
    backOff.setMultiplier(1.5);
    backOff.setMaxInterval(30_000);
    backOff.setMaxElapsedTime(120_000);
    factory.setRecoveryBackOff(backOff);
    return factory;
}
```

Comment: I do not understand where I should write this code. In the main spring class and autowire it as a bean as a java config? How will I add it to my listener class with the @RabbitListener ?

Comment: Sorry - there's a simpler solution; you can add the `BackOff` to the listener container factory instead of post-processing the containers - I updated the answer.